# How to convert COFF to OMF?

Tags: c++, coff, omf

I have a third party program that has a runtime interface that I can add to my programs. In the directory for the runtime interface is a .lib file and a .hpp file. I have a Borland compiler so I need to convert the files but I am not sure which ones or how. Previously I had converted the files in a project (over 20 years ago) and I had a .hpp, .lib and a .def.

I assume the third party program was with a MS compiler. Now I need to make it work with Borland. An OLD version of Borland (5.0) C++.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Is the `.lib` file a *static library*, or is it a DLL *import library*?  It makes a BIG difference in how you handle it.

Comment: Object file convertor might help you:
https://agner.org/optimize/#objconv
https://digitalmars.com/ctg/coff2omf.html
https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#EaFnConvert

Comment: Library is static.